# Upper bound for the number of coprimes to primes below $x$ in an arbitrary interval of length $x$?

Tags: prime-numbers, sieve-theory

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a subset of the primes up to $x^{{1/2}-o(1)}$ and let $S(T,T+x;\mathcal{E})$ be the number of integers in the interval $(T,T+x]$ that are coprime to the primes in $\mathcal{E}$. The upper bound for $S(T,T+x;\mathcal{E})$ (see ["When the sieve works"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.0413)) is then:

$$
S(T,T+x;\mathcal{E}) \ll x \prod_{p\in\mathcal{E}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p} \right).
$$

> QUESTION: What is the best achievable upper bound in the case when $\mathcal{E}$ is the set of all primes $\leq x$?